# How to get all task's id in celery

Tags: python-3.x, redis, celery, celery-task

I should to get a list of all tasks with their statuses without knowing the task id. I think it can work with result_backend, but i don't understand how it work. Help please!

I check internet and trying coding.

Answer (score 0):

Celery has monitoring/inspection API which gives you this ability. You can use it in your Python programs as well as from Celery CLI

When you run something like `celery -A your.celery.app inspect --help` you get something like (change `your.celery.app` with the right parameter for you):

```
Usage: celery inspect [OPTIONS] {report|conf|query_task|clock|ping|stats|sched
                      uled|reserved|active|revoked|registered|objgraph|memsamp
                      le|memdump|active_queues}

  Inspect the worker at runtime.

  Availability: RabbitMQ (AMQP) and Redis transports.

Remote Control Options:
  -t, --timeout FLOAT             Timeout in seconds waiting for reply.
  -d, --destination COMMA SEPARATED LIST
                                  Comma separated list of destination node
                                  names.
  -j, --json                      Use json as output format.

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

As you can see, there are many options but for what you asked most important are:

- scheduled - list scheduled tasks
- reserved - list reserved tasks
- active - list tasks that are running at the moment this CLI command gets executed
- revoked - list revoked tasks

I encourage you to get familiar with others as well as they are all very usefu.

Finally, keep in mind monitoring/inspect API works only with two broker types - Redis and RabbitMQ. If you use something else you can't use the API unfortunately.